# I am trying to render HTML inside of a textfield from material UI

Tags: material-ui

I am trying to display(readonly) html markup inside of the material UI  however when I do it shows the html tags.

Below account.mission contains the markup text. I thought of using dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: getMarkup()}} however the Texfield does not seem to allow that.

The reason I choose TextField is that I want to have a border when using the label that shows the word "Our Mission" inside the border lines.

Is there another way to do this where I could use a Div and still get the same effect? Div will allow me to render the HTML but I do not know how to show the word "Our Mission" as part of the border outline.

**Here is what I am using right now and it displays all of the HTML tags:**

```
<TextField
 label='Our Mission'
 value={account.mission}  // This contains HTML and currently shows the tags.  
 InputProps={{
 readOnly: true,
 }}
 InputLabelProps={{
 shrink: true,
 }}
 variant='outlined'
 fullWidth
 multiline
 rows={5} 
 rowsMax={Infinity} // Allow unlimited expansion
 inputProps={{
 style: {
 whiteSpace: 'pre-wrap',
 overflowWrap: 'break-word',
 },
 }}
/>
```